# Validar que una cadena cumple un formato especifico en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validación, validate

Tengo un input type: text y quiero validar que tenga el siguiente formato: **00001-00000123**,
es decir, que sea de 13 dígitos **numéricos** con un guion luego del 5to dígito.

```html
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <label>Guia<span class="red-color"> *</span></label>
      <input type="text"
         ng-model="$ctrl.nominacion.Guia"
         name="Guia"
         class="form-control"
         ng-maxlength="14"
         ng-minlength="14"
         autocomplete="Guia-off"
         ng-class="{'is-invalid': ($ctrl.nominacionForm.Guia.$touched || $ctrl.nominacionForm.$submitted) && $ctrl.nominacionForm.Guia.$invalid}">
      <span ng-show="$ctrl.nominacionForm.Guia.$invalid" class="red-color">Formato de dígitos incorrecto</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En JavaScript existen las expresiones regulares (RegEx), las cuales sirven para hacer cosas de este estilo. En tu caso, quieres comprobar el siguiente formato:`00001-00000123`.

Para ello, deberas hacer lo siguiente:

```js
    const entrada = "00001-00000123";
    const cmpReg = /\d{5}-\d{8}/;
    if(entrada.match(cmpReg)) {
        console.log("Cumple el formato")
    } else {
        console.log("No se cumple el formato")
    }
```

En resumen, lo que hace esta expresion regular, es comprobar que la entrada usa el siguiente formato en este orden:

```
1.- Comienza con 5 digitos cualquiera
2.- Tiene un guión despues de los 5 digitos
3.- Finaliza con 8 digitos cualquiera y es el FINAL de la cadena de texto.
```

En el código adjunto arriba, puedes alternar el valor de la constante `entrada` y probar a ver que ocurre si no cumple el formato que especificaste. Si se cumple el formato, lo dirá por consola, en caso contrario, dirá en consola que no se cumple.

Para mas informacion sobre este regex, incluyo un link el cual explica este regex y que hace cada simbolo. [Aqui](https://regex101.com/r/nBeGa8/1).

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por el aporte! me sirvió :)